# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: login failed for user '......'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, iis

I use no Integrated Security. I've looked this problem up online and tried solving the error. So far nothing worked or solved it. It doesn't work with both iis and debug in visual studio. This is the error I'm getting:

**Details van uitzondering:** System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user '.....'.

**Fout in bron:**

```
Regel 7:    {
Regel 8:        SqlConnection myconnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionClass.cnnConnectionVacature);
Regel 9:        myconnection.Open();
Regel 10: 
Regel 11:       //het laten zien van ingevoerde database gegevens
```

**Bronbestand:** c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Vacaturesite\start.aspx.cs    Regel: 9

**Stacktracering:**

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'BPVICTwebuser'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5340655
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +244
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1691
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +69
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +30
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +317
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +891
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +307
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData) +518
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +278
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +732
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +85
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1057
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +196
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +146
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +16
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +94
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +110
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
   Start.Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Vacaturesite\start.aspx.cs:9
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Page.OnInit(EventArgs e) +12
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +134
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +489
```

here is some of the code:

```
public static string cnnConnectionVacature
{
    get { return @"Data Source=SX047H\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BPVICT_vacature;User ID=...;Password=..."; }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that you have the Mixed-Mode authentication enabled and here is a step-by-step article describing how to enable it http://www.lansweeper.com/kb/23/SQLserver-enable-mixed-authentication.html

Comment: Are you sure that the user id & password is valid also have you confirmed that the user has permission on the database

Comment: Tbh I'm not really sure. I got a project in which I got a website with a database. I didn't change anything to the database except for the data source.

Comment: I checked the login id and password. They're both valid. And the user has permission. Still get the error. I have no idea what else to try

Comment: Try to login with this username & password through the SQL Server management studio

Comment: Hmm... login failed for user 'BPVICTwebuser'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456) I normally use Windows Authentication btw

Comment: So now it is not your code, it is either user disabled, mixed mode disabled, user doesn't have permission on the DB :)

Comment: OMG! Thanks! I figured it out ! It finally works ^_^

Comment: @Zephyr I'm facing the same error, but I don't know how to find which is the user id. Could you help me? Thanks!